# Date formatting for axis in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to make a series of horizontal line plots that connect between the time and date of arrival to the time and date of departure.

[image]

The issue is that to be able to make these horisontal plots I need to make the date and time component continuous and convert it to decimal. Then when displaying the plot the x axis shows the decimal representation rather than the date.
The date time information I have is of the form 08-11-2019 00:03 (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm). When I convet it to decimal in Tableau it converts to a number representing the number of days since the 1st Jan 1900. As far as I am aware to display the data on the same plot like this I need the data to be decimal and continuous (I am open to alternative suggestions to achieve the same output).
As a result of this my x-axis looks like this:

[image]

Which is supposed to represent date and time information and this is not meaningfull.
Is there any way of using the continuous decimal information to produce the plot but display the x axis as at least date information (time split not needed).

The workbook and data example can be found here: https://community.tableau.com/message/1016957#1016957

Comment: Answer in the link should give you what you have asked. have you tried it?

Comment: Added his response as an answer below. Thanks :)

Comment: IT is possible to handle this with a normal date axis formatted however you like. But you need a *single* date axis and a separate *event* dimension that classifies whether the date is an arrival or a departure (which requires a little data restructuring). But this structure makes many analyses of different events over time far easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as dates are stored as number in computers, you can change the display settings on formatting and display it back as a date (using the custom option)....

[image]

Hope that helps

Anserwed by Simon Runc on https://community.tableau.com/message/1017135#1017135 
Thank you.

Comment: did it help or not?